# useState is resetting to default after initial and every subsequent render in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

the below code is not returning any errors but is not working either as per the logic.

So below are two components, APP() as parent component and Signin() as child component, in parent component i am use useEffect and whenever there is render happens it first check the server with cookies if valid then it will update the siginalready= true(initial default value is false) and then will pass the state to the child component, but when next  time i refresh the page it takes as siginalready=false   as initial value (which is odd as it should be true  already after first time).

This behaviour of resetting the state value of  siginalready is effecting the project as when second time (i click account information it fist shows me the loginpage(siginalready =false) and then in less than a second it shows me the account info page((siginalready =true).
i got a feeling that it is something i am missing with useEffect function,  but i dont see any thing wrong in it. any suggestions guys.

this is the snippet from Parent component.

```
import Signin from "./Component/Signin";

function App() {

  const [siginalready, setifsignedin] = useState(false);

  const [userinfonew, setUserinfo] = useState([]);



  let url = "http://localhost:5000/api/verifyifloginalready";

  let options = {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "POST",
  };
  let verifyifloginalready = new Request(url, options);


  useEffect(() => {
    credentailverify();
  }, []);



  function credentailverify() {
    (async () => {
      const x1 = await fetch(verifyifloginalready)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status == 400 || res.status == 401) {
            console.log(res.status);
            // to do call delete current  cookies function
            return setifsignedin(false);
          } else if (siginalready == false) {
            setifsignedin(true);

            return res.json();
          } else {
            return;
          }
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setUserinfo(data.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("err"));

      return x1;
    })();
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="header">
          <Nav userinfo={userinfonew} userstatus={siginalready} />
        </header>

        <div className="main">
          <Sidebar />
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/"
              exact
           
              render={(props) => <Home {...props} userinfo={userinfonew} />}
            />
           
            from router {/* render={props=>(<newComponent}/> )} */}
           
            />
            <Route
              path="/signin"
              exact
              render={(props) => (
                <Signin
                  {...props}
                  userinfo={userinfonew}
                  userstatus={siginalready}
                />
              )}
            />
           
          </Switch>
        </div>

        <div className="footer">
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1> Home page</h1>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

The below is the snippet of code from Child component

```
function Signin({ userinfo, userstatus }) {
return (
    <div>
      {userstatus ? (
        <Useraccount newuserinfo={userinfo} updateduserstatus={userstatus} />
      ) : (
        <SigninOptions  />
      )}
    </div>
  );

}
export default Signin;
```

Comment: i made a small clip to show the issue i am facing. whenever i click signin it first shows me login page and then the useraccount page, everytime i refresh      https://youtu.be/RFoGEqEcuys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when next time i refresh the page it takes as siginalready=false as initial value (which is odd as it should be true already after first time)

This is what you've done:

```js
const [siginalready, setifsignedin] = useState(false);
```

`siginalready` get `false` as a default value. `credentailverify` is an async function, so it takes time for it to call `setifsignedin(true)`.

That's why `SigininOptions` component is rendered at the first time.

You can save login status after successful login to fix this:

```js
// Put this function outside of App component
const isLoggedIn = () => {
   // user info can be loaded after refresh
   return !!window.localStorage.getItem('user-info'); // !! : cast to boolean
}

// And then inside App component
const [siginalready, setifsignedin] = useState(isLoggedIn());

function credentailverify() {
    (async () => {
      const x1 = await fetch(verifyifloginalready)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status == 400 || res.status == 401) {
            console.log(res.status);
            // to do call delete current  cookies function
            window.localStorage.removeItem('user-info');
            return setifsignedin(false);
          } else if (siginalready == false) {
            setifsignedin(true);

            return res.json();
          } else {
            return;
          }
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setUserinfo(data.data);
          // save user login status
          window.localStorage.setItem('user-info', JSON.stringify(data.data));
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("err"));

      return x1;
    })();
  }
```

**IMPORTANT**: You might want to handle authentication with JWT for SPA including react in a real world program.

Comment: thanks alot it does work. just to confirm if i have understand the code, correctly,  we always have to save the data in local storage so that we can retrieve it after the refresh. also i am struggling to understand the reason of using  boolean (!!) when we use !!window.localStorage.getItem('user-info');  in the above code, how does the boolean helping here?

Comment: @Umair_007 If you don't cast it to boolean, `signialready` will be an object holding user info, while in this case, it should be boolean.